# ansi to unicode conversion

Tags: c#, encoding, typography

While parsing certain documents, I get the character code 146, which is actually an ANSI number. While writing the char to text file, nothing is shown. If we write the char as Unicode number- 8217, the character is displayed fine.

Can anyone give me advice on how to convert the ANSI number 146 to Unicode 8217 in C#.

reference: http://www.alanwood.net/demos/ansi.html

Thanks

Comment: Are you reading files?  You can set the encoding as you open the file for reading...

Answer (score 8):

"ANSI" is really a misnomer - there are many encodings often known as "ANSI". However, if you're sure you need code page 1252, you can use:

```
Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText(filename, encoding))
{
    // Read text and use it
}
```

or

```
Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
string text = File.ReadAllText(filename, encoding);
```

That's for *reading* a file - writing a file is the same idea. Basically when you're converting from binary (e.g. file contents) to text, use an appropriate [`Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) object.

Comment: HI Jon,

Thank you for the details. 

Actually, I get only the character code (146) from a document and it is a PDF document and not a text file. Thereby I need to convert the code to corresponding text.

So, could you please give me an idea on how to convert the code say, 146 to 8712, instead of using the TextReader class.

Comment: @user438959: It's not really clear what you mean. The PDF reader should take care of the encoding for you. If it's applying the wrong encoding, it's basically too late - you can easily have lost data already.

Comment: I am extracting the text from the PDF. The encoding of the character is winansi encoding and the character code is 146 (right singe quotation mark). How can I write the character to a text file having only the character code (146).

Comment: @user438959: It's still not clear what you mean. When you say "the character code" do you mean you've got the data correctly as a Unicode string and want to just *write* it to a CP-1252 text file, or you're having trouble *reading* it correctly?

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation would be to read [Joel's "Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).  There's quite a lot involved in your question and my experience has been that you'll just struggle against the simple answers if you don't understand these basics.  It takes around 15 minutes to read.